# How to compare two sets with custom datatypes

Tags: c++, stl, set

I need to check if two sets with a custom data type are equal. Here's my code:

```
#include <set>

struct Status
{
    int x;
    bool y;

    Status() : x(0), y(false){}
};

struct StatusComparator
{
    bool operator() (const Status& s1, const Status& s2)
    {
        return (s2.x > s1.x);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::set<Status, StatusComparator> s1, s2;
    auto x = s1 == s2;

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
```

I have tried using the *std::set_symmetric_difference()* method instead of the equality operator and that also gives me the same result.

Update:
I overloaded the == operator for Status

```
bool operator == (const Status& s)
{
    return x == s.x && y == s.y;
}
```

I still get the same error as before.

Using the std::equal works fine.

```
StatusComparator ob;
auto x = std::equal(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), ob);
```

Comment: In GCC I'm getting the following error: `error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const Status' and 'const Status')` - set tries to compare each of its elements and it fails because there is no comparison operator for `Status`

Comment: as @rafix07 mentioned, you will have to implement the overload of operator '==' for struct `Status`

Comment: I think, he should use `std::equal` since he uses a custom comparator. `std::equal` can take a binary predicate to assert equality which can be defined in terms of `StatusComparator`. `operator==(const std::set&, const std::set&)` doesn't provide that flexibility which – I think – OP wants since he didn't implemented `Status::operator<` either.

Comment: If a comparator is a member funciton than it must be a `const` member function in your case, since it is applied to constant objects (keys). It works then: https://godbolt.org/z/0cYep3.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I had to overload the == operator.

```
bool operator== (const Status& s) const
{
    return x == s.x && y == s.y;
}
```